# How to apply FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) to pick a folder

Tags: excel, vba, directory, picker

I'm trying to add a folder selection dialog to my code.

I get

> run-time error "Object variable or With block variable not set"

```vb
Dim ofso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Long, colFolders As New Collection, ws As Worksheet
 
Set ws = Sheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet, After:=ActiveSheet)
Set ofso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Set oFolder = ofso.GetFolder("F:\") This is the line to be replaced with the folder picker and what was being used before.
'Start folder picker
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'Check if user clicked cancel button
    oFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
```

Then the code resumes with everything else that works when not using the folder picker.

It gives the error at

```
oFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
```

I tried playing with my object names

```vb
Set oFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With oFolder
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'Check if user clicked cancel button
    oFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
```

Full code without the folder picker, to show what I'm trying to do.

```vb
Sub GetFilesColFunc()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ofso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim i As Long, colFolders As New Collection, ws As Worksheet
 
    Set ws = Sheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet, After:=ActiveSheet)
    Set ofso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = ofso.GetFolder("F:\")
    
    On Error Resume Next
           
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = "File Name"
    ws.Cells(1, 2) = "File Type"
    ws.Cells(1, 3) = "Date Created"
    ws.Cells(1, 4) = "Date Last Modified"
    ws.Cells(1, 5) = "Date Last Accessed"
    ws.Cells(1, 6) = "File Path"
    
    Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    Rows(1).Font.Size = 11
    Rows(1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
    Range("C:E").Columns.AutoFit
           
    colFolders.Add oFolder          'start with this folder
    
    Do While colFolders.Count > 0      'process all folders
        Set oFolder = colFolders(1)    'get a folder to process
        colFolders.Remove 1            'remove item at index 1
                    
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            
                ws.Cells(i + 2, 1) = oFile.Name
                ws.Cells(i + 2, 2) = oFile.Type
                ws.Cells(i + 2, 3) = oFile.DateCreated
                ws.Cells(i + 2, 4) = oFile.DateLastModified
                ws.Cells(i + 2, 5) = oFile.DateLastAccessed
                ws.Cells(i + 2, 6) = oFolder.Path
                i = i + 1
            
        Next oFile

        'add any subfolders to the collection for processing
        For Each sf In oFolder.SubFolders
            If Not SkipFolder(sf.Name) Then colFolders.Add sf 'Skips folders listed within the referenced function
        Next sf
           
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: it might be .SelectedItems(0) - array is probably zero-based

Comment: Tried simply setting it to 0 and it still isn't working.

Comment: If you are trying the code as pasted, the  `oFolder` object is not set (the line is commented out).

Comment: That commented out line is actually what I was using before. I did try a variant changing the variable names as

`    Set oFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With oFolder
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'Check if user clicked cancel button
        oFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With`

and it's still not working.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve with `oFolder =`, with `oFolder` being an `Object`. If you meant to replace the `"F:\"` in `Set oFolder = ofso.GetFolder("F:\")` with `.SelectedItems(1) & "\"`, then `Set oFolder = ofso.GetFolder(.SelectedItems(1) & "\")`.

Comment: I edited my question with my full code without the folder picker to show what I'm trying to do. Maybe that clarifies my goal here? And possibly shows how much I don't actually understand what I'm doing :P I just want to add a folder picker dialog into this so I can have someone else also use this macro without having to edit code every time they need a different directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing things, probably because you stared at your code for too long :)

I botched together an example for you that hopefully illustrates some of the confusing stuff. Please note: I haven't done VBA in ages

I divided up your problem into a few subsections.

A `FileDialog` (aka the folderpicker built-in in Office) returns strings. So I put that into its own function.

You cannot simply create an FSO `Folder` object by assigning a string to it. That is not how objects work, you have to bring them to live with the `Set` keyword. When you are new to VBS/VBA that is hard to understand at first. The `GetFolder` method from the Windows Scripting Host's `FileSystemObject` returns a `Folder` object. I put the output of that in the `GetFSOFolder` function. The `GetFSOFolder` returns an object, so you have to `Set` the variable (`oFolder`) that captures it

Without the fluff that you decorated your OP with, here is an example of how you *could* approach this to just get the `oFolder` in your OP.

It is probably longer than you want it to be, the reason being that I hope to clarify some things by being elaborate about it.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim sFolder As String
    sFolder = FolderPicker() 'get the string representation from FileDialog
    If sFolder = "" Then
        Debug.Print "No folder was selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'create a Folder object from the string
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Set oFolder = GetFSOFolder(sFolder)

    'what do we have?
    Debug.Print "Selected folder was: " & oFolder.path
    
End Sub

Function GetFSOFolder(path As String) As Object 'returns a Folder object if path is valid
    
    Dim ofso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set ofso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set GetFSOFolder = ofso.GetFolder(path) 'note the Set, we are returning an object

End Function

Function FolderPicker() As String 'takes care of the folder picking dialog stuff
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
    'Start folder picker
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Function 'Check if user clicked cancel button
        FolderPicker = .SelectedItems(1) '.SelectedItems(1) returns a string!
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying to learn VBA by accomplishing some much needed tasks for my employer, and it's been a struggle. I can tell there are some concepts that I am just not getting, or mixing up or conflating. Your answer helps clear up a few things for me and helps me actually see what it is I'm missing. When learning from nothing more than Google, it can be hard to know what it is I need to know and this actually shed light clearly on a few things. At the least, I now know a couple important concepts I need to focus some studying on.
Thank you!!!